# Why do we need to set SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Can any one tell me what is meant by sonar-runner-opts and its use?

```
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS:-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=10240m
```

What is the difference between java-opts and sonar-opts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is used to customized parameters passed to the JVM **when you launch a SonarQube analysis on your project** with the `sonar-runner` command line executable.

For instance, you might have a big project for which a lot of RAM is required by the JVM to be able to run the full analysis without getting an `OutOfMemoryError`: you can increase the max size of the JVM heap using this environment variable.

This means that those parameters do not impact other programs but only SonarQube Runner.